# error while inserting mm-dd-yyyy date in mysql in coldfusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

i have a problem while inserting the date format like  mm/dd/yyyy in mySQL.
 It is showing the date format error.and my requirement is to enter like this format from front-end(coldfusion) and i am using mySQL5 as database.
any help would be greatly appriaciated.

Thanks
Yugal

Comment: It would help if you'd shown us the code that you're using to make the insert. In the absence of code, my guess would be that your dates are ambiguous (mm/dd/yyyy format is often a cause of confusion). Why not just re-arrange the date to a sane format - ie yyyy-mm-dd, the MySQL default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the date to save is a valid date and either use `CreateODBCDate(yourDate)` or `CreateODBCDateTime(yourDate)` or better let `<cfqueryparam>` do the work for you

```
INSERT into myTable
(myDate)
VALUES
(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_date" value="#yourDate#">)
```

Comment: In fact, cfqueryparam should handle this without additional converting.

Comment: @Sergii you're right. cfqueryparam can do the conversion for you. I mixed up doing the query with and without cfqueryparam. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: If this date is a value being entered from the user, you really should be using cfqueryparam.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're entering dates in date columns and not string values, as the default cast of string --> date in the database could change at any time.

e.g.

```
insert into TableX (myDateCol) SELECT STR_TO_DATE('01,5,2013','%d,%m,%Y') ...
```

and not

```
insert into TableX (myDateCol) SELECT '05/01/2013' ...
```

or however that is constructed in coldfusion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to mention which format you are giving.

```
Insert into table TABLE values(XX,'TO_DATE('03-10-92','MM-DD-YY')',XXXXX);
```

Comment: TO_DATE is not a mysql function (use STR_TO_DATE)