# Coldfusion change time format to mm/dd/yyyy from SQL form

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

This is my code but it doesn't seem to change the datetime format in my table. How can I fix the format?

```
<cfset LOCAL.time_from = DateFormat(ARGUMENTS.myForm.Time_From, "mm/dd/yyyy") />

<cfquery name="LOCAL.myURL" datasource="#SERVER.cfc.core.getDSN()#">
    INSERT INTO logboek.tbl_Time (Time_begin,Time_end,Time_total)
     VALUES (
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.Time_begin#" />,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.Time_end#" />,
        <cfqueryparam value="#DateFormat(ARGUMENTS.myForm.Time_From, "mm/dd/yyyy")# ">,
        TIMEDIFF(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.Time_end#" />, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" value="#ARGUMENTS.myForm.Time_begin#" />)
    );
</cfquery>
```

**Update from comments:**

The database has the correct format, but the table that shows it on the web doesn't.  I have: `{ts '2016-01-26 15:00:00'}` in my table, but in my database I have: `26-1-2016 15:00`. What I have in the database is also what I want to display in my table.

Comment: The database stores the value as a date time data type. You format it when you display it.

Comment: Your insert statement specifies 3 columns. But you have 4 values.

Comment: *as a date time data type* .. which is basically a big number. They are not actually stored as 'mm/dd/yyyy' strings. That is just how your IDE displays them.  As John said, store the values as date/time objects and convert them to human friendly strings when displayed.  Side note, looks like your INSERT list is missing a column and the cfqueryparam is missing a `cfsqltype`. To insert a date only, use `cf_sql_date`.

Comment: @JohnWhish - You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: On the same theme of proper datatypes, in your very first cfset command, the ParseDateTime() function is more appropriate than DateFormat().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date format error in ColdFusion and mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170245/date-format-error-in-coldfusion-and-mysql)

Comment: (Edit) @DanBracuk - That seems like a different issue. ie Handling/conversion of dd/mm/yyyy into mm/dd/yyyy. Though not entirely clear, this one seems to be about how date/time values are stored in the database, generally.

Comment: the database has the correct format but the table that shows it on the web doesnt

Comment: This question, especially the code, has nothing to do with displaying data on a web page.

Comment: @NadalRahman -  As mentioned above, none of the code in your post has anything to do with displaying a date on a web page ... Please post the *relevant* code and an example of the actual value displayed AND how it is different than what you expected.

Comment: i have: {ts '2016-01-26 15:00:00'}                                                                               in my table but in my database i have:26-1-2016 15:00                                                                    what i have in the database is also what i want to display in my table

Comment: That is ODBC format. It is how datetime objects are displayed by default if you do not specify a different format. Take a look at [date and time format functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateFormat.html). You did not mention your version, but for CF10+ there are [additional options](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateTimeFormat.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @leigh suggested, you can just use `dateTimeFormat()` or combination of `dateFormat()` and `timeFormat()` (depending on your CF version) to format the date while displaying in table. Like this:

**ColdFusion 10+**

```
writeOutput(dateTimeFormat(variable_containing_date, "d-m-yyyy HH:nn"))
```

**Or in CF versions below 10**

```
writeOutput(dateFormat(variable_containing_date, "d-m-yyyy")) & " " & timeFormat(variable_containing_date, "HH:mm")))
```